# Kotlin: Blocking coroutines with non-blocking I/O

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

I'm trying to use Kotlin coroutines to handle a non-blocking I/O. Scenario is as follows:

1. Receive data from an asynchronous callback running on thread 1.
2. Wait for this data in thread 2 then consume it.

My current code looks like this (simplified for sake of brevity):

```
private var latch = CountDownLatch(1)
private var data: Any? = null

// Async callback from non-blocking I/O
fun onReceive(data: Any) {
    currentData = data
    latch.countDown()
}

// Wait and consume data
fun getData(): Any? {
    latch.await()
    latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    return currentData
}

fun processData() {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        while (true) {
            val data = getData()
            // Consume data                
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, Kotlin coroutines should be able to help me to get rid of CountDownLatch. After reading [this (awesome) guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md), all I could come up with is something like this:

```
// Wait and consume data
fun getData() = async(CommonPool) {
    latch.await()
    latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    currentData
}

fun processData() {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        while (true) {
            runBlocking {
                val data = getData().await()
                // Consume data                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with [Pipelines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#pipelines), with similar results. I'm obviously not understanding how to use these features.

Comment: From the code in the question it is kinda hard to understand what was your goal. Please clarify what external function returns what.

Comment: In this scenario one needs to know what API calls return promises and of what types. Please add this info to the question

Comment: @voddan My goal is to wait for data from a non-blocking source to be ready and process it (the actual source is user input but I think this is irrelevant because it could be different non-blocking sources). The non-blocking source calls `onReceive()` when data is ready to be processed. Data type is irrelevant, you can consider it any type that suits you best (in my actual code the data type is a custom class).

Comment: do not use CountDownLatch. Use ArrayBlockingQueue instead. Let onReceive() call queue.put(); and processData() call queue.take() instead of getData().

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Nice point, will do. Still I do not understand in what scenario should I use coroutines.

Comment: The correct answer depends on how you initiate the asynchronous operation that will later invoke your `onReceive` callback and whether you are expecting callback to be invoked just once or multiple times. Please, clarify your question to get the right answer.

Comment: @RomanElizarov I simply use `thread {}`. It is expected to be called multiple times.

Comment: So if it is expected to be called multiple times, then how your original code with `CountDownLatch` is supposed to work? E.g., think what happens when `onReceive` is invoked for the second time, while `getData` has completed its first line (with `await`) but has not executed its second line yet. I'm just trying to figure what you are trying to achieve, which is absolutely not clear from your original code.

Comment: @RomanElizarov Yes, you're correct, the code is flawed indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not said if data received in `onReceive()` can be processed in parallel. This is the main question. If yes, you can just do it in `onReceive()`. If this is not allowed, let each call to `onReceive()` start a task on `CommonPool`, without any coroutines. If they should be processed sequentially, then simplest way is to start a thread with a loop inside:

```
fun onReceive(data: Any) {
   queue.put(data);
}

 ....

// loop in a thread
while(true) {
   data = queue.take();
   processData(data);
}
```

Again, coroutines are not needed.

Generally, coroutines are syntactic sugar to represent an asynchronous program as if it is synchronous. I do not think your program as a case to use coroutines.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very common pattern using `CountDownLatch` when developing with Android, sometimes you want to make an async implementation to be sync when dealing with `BroadcastReceivers` and `CountDownLatch` is pretty handy.

```
private suspend fun yourSuspendMethod() {
    val job = GlobalScope.async {    
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

        val watcher = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                if // your logic
                    latch.countDown()
            }
        }

        try {
            mContext?.registerReceiver(watcher, IntentFilter(...))

            //call a method that will trigger the broadcast receiver

            if (!latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                throw Exception("Failed .... on latch's timeout")
            }
        } finally {
            mContext?.unregisterReceiver(watcher)
        }
    }

    job.await()
}
```

There is one very important thing in here, DO NOT change the context of the CoroutineScope, otherwise they will be running in a completely different place, by doing the way I left above it becomes a child of the scope/context.

[EDIT]
I decided to put more thoughts into this problem to avoid using `CountDownLatch`. The problem of the latch is that when you call `latch.await` it will stop the current thread, so if this is coming from a Main thread, the Main will wait and it will timeout because it didn't give a chance for the receiver to be called. A way to solve this is by using the example that I used above.

One thing I forgot on the example above is that if you want to unit test and synchronize the context of the caller you will need to inject the context. If you decide to do that your implementation will become a bit more complex and you will not be using the full power of the coroutine, because you will be creating extra threads.

So, the solution would be using a combination of `withTimeout` + `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, you can use this extension:

```
suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineWithTimeout(
    timeout: Long,
    crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Unit
) = withTimeout(timeout) {
    suspendCancellableCoroutine(block = block)
}
```

and your method would look like this:

```
private suspend fun yourSuspendMethod() {
    var watcher: BroadcastReceiver? = null

    try {
        suspendCoroutineWithTimeout<Boolean>(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)) {
            watcher = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

                override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                    if // your logic
                        it.resume(true)
                }
            }

            context?.registerReceiver(watcher, IntentFilter(...))
            //call a method that will trigger the broadcast receiver
        }
    } finally {
        context?.unregisterReceiver(watcher)
    }
}
```

That would be it. Now coroutine would do its magic without stoping the caller thread and when the job gets canceled the timeout will also cancel.